# "Solution for" or "solution to" a problem?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

> I need to find a solution to/for this problem.

Can *to* and *for* be used interchangeably here? Is one of them just plain wrong?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> - I need to find a solution *to* this problem
> - I need to find a solution *for* this problem
> - I need to find a remedy *for* this problem

All three sentences are correct, although the second is less common. Usually, one will find that *to* is the preposition of choice for the word *solution*. However, *for* is preferred in certain cases, and I give two examples to illustrate this:

> - A bunch of students are working on a physics problem set in the common room. *C* and *J* are done with questions 1 through 4 and are currently working on 5. *A* just finished solving question 4 and wants to check her work with *C* and *J*: "Hey guys, could you show me your solution ***for*** number four? I'm not sure I did it correctly."
> - Joe had just bought a fridge for a dollar from an old lady down the road. Still unable to believe his luck, he wasted no time in setting it up in the corner of the hovel he shared with his brother, Alex. Only after plugging in the fridge did Joe realize that the door wouldn't close properly. He repeatedly slammed the door shut only to have it slowly creak open each time to his chagrin. "Hey, bro," Alex finally said, "calm down. Calm down!" He pulled out a crowbar. "There's a quick solution ***for*** this."

Comment: I'm with Jimi here. 'For' sounds right in the examples, but I still don't know why. Interesting though!

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Alas, like @mvexel, I know not why. It just sounds/works better in these cases.

Comment: @Jasper: Thanks a lot for the link! Definitely helps to know this!

Comment: I wonder what Jasper said—sounds like it was of use. To me, the difference between a solution _to_ a problem and a solution _for_ a problem is that the latter indicates a possible, suggested solution (yet to be verified as something that truly solves the problem), while the former is a more definitely efficient solution—if applicable, the _only_ possible solution. I’m not sure if this distinction is only in my head, or whether it always holds true, but it seems to me to work at least in the examples given here.

Comment: @Janus: Interesting comment. Unfortunately, I have *no* recollection of whatever Jasper said! It's been two long years :)

Comment: But why is *for* preferred in those 2 examples? What is wrong of using *to*? By the way, will we prefer to say "a solution *for* someone who needs one"?

Answer (score 18):

I would use 'to' exclusively. The problem has a solution, the solution belongs to the problem.  I will find a solution *to* the problem *for* my boss, because that's what he pays me to do.

I will agree with both RGB and JasperLoy that if I heard "a solution for the problem" I wouldn't think it was necessarily incorrect, it just doesn't sound as good to me.

Answer (score 13):

As a native English speaker I regard *to* and *for* as interchangeable in the sentence you quoted. I would probably use *for* more often, but I wouldn't regard *to* as wrong.

Update: I searched the British National Corpus (BNC) at Brigham Young University (BYU). [BYU-BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) found 1165 examples of "solution to" but only 208 examples of "solution for".

Comment: Thanks RGB. Do you think there's a cultural preference for either in the UK or the US?

Comment: @mvexel: I tried to search the British National Corpus for "solution to" and "solution for". In both cases the response was "no solutions found *for* this query" (my emphasis)

Comment: @RGB: that's hilarious. I did not know of this resource, thanks for pointing it out.