# “Solution to” vs. “solution of ”

Tags: differences, prepositions, to-of

What is the difference between saying *solution **to** the problem* and saying *solution **of** the problem*?

Are they both equivalent, or is there some difference?

Comment: Related: [solution for or to a problem?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14753/solution-for-or-to-a-problem)

Comment: similar, but "for" is not "of" :-) Maybe we should combine the two questions...

Comment: The answer to the other question is the same for this question.

Comment: Is `2` the solution *to* the equation `x-2=0`, or is it a solution *of* the equation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost always hear "solution to the problem" and sometimes "solution for the problem" — but almost never do you hear "of" in that context.

> **solution** |səˈloō sh ən|
>   *noun*
>   1 a means of solving a problem or dealing with a difficult situation : *there are no easy solutions to financial and marital problems*.
>   • the correct answer to a puzzle : *the solution to this month's crossword*.

Note that both of NOAD's examples use *to*.

One would use "solution of" if one is referring to a chemical solution:

> 2 a liquid mixture in which the minor component (the solute) is uniformly distributed within the major component (the solvent).

Comment: Hmm: http://www.google.com/search?q="solution+of"+site%3Awikipedia.org

Comment: Following on from @mplungjan... there's a difference in meaning between *The solution to that problem was satisfying*, and *The solution of that problem was satisfying* - i.e. whether it's the result or the process that was satisfying.

Comment: How about an equation? "Find the solution of x+2=4" vs. "Find the solution to x+2=4" ?

Comment: I would still prefer *to* there.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the context. The main distinction is that *solution* has more than one meaning:

- An *answer* to the problem (fully worked out), but also
- The *process* of finding such an answer (i.e. a synonym for *solving*)
- Something dissolved in something else (say, sugar dissolved in water)

With the first meaning, use *to*:

> I have found a solution to your problem.

With the second, use *of*:

> The solution of those problems took me a long time.
>
> The solution of difficult problems is very satisfying.

Note that choice of *to* versus *of* can change the meaning:

> The solution to that problem will take you an hour. [Finding the solution took a year, but carrying it out takes an hour.]
>
> The solution of that problem will take you an hour. [It will take an hour to solve it.]

When talking about something dissolved in something else (usually in chemistry), use *of*:

> This drink is basically a solution of sugar in water.

Answer (score 5):

It depends heavily on the context.

In colloquial usage you almost always (from personal experience) hear solution to the problem, maybe sometimes solution for the problem (As in - "I have a solution for/to your problem")

In mathematics however, "Solution of" can be used as well (e.g. "A solution *of* the differential equation" *however* "A solution *to* the system of differential equations"). Perhaps  the tense of the object, and the fact that it can *possess* solutions (rather than be solved by solutions as above) allows one to use the "of" form.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there does exist a slight difference between saying 'solution to' and 'solution of'.

When using the 'of' form, we are treating the solution as an attribute of that problem, i.e. we are more confident about the correctness of the solution.

When using the 'to' form, we are relatively less confident about that, sometimes we are just being in the middle of the process of proving the correctness of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only usage of 'solution of' that seems right to be is in the chemical sense.  E.g. "A weak solution of calcium chloride in water."