# "definition of" vs "definition for"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I'm learning the new word "definition" and there are two example sentences listed on my app:

1. What’s your definition `of` happiness?
2. I need a definition `for` this word.

Should I use "of" or "for" after "definition"? Or both are OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both:

> 1. What’s **your definition of** happiness?
> 2. I need **a definition for** this word.

are correct.

Note should be taken of the fact that with definite determiners (in this case "your") the preposition "of" will be preferred, while with an indefinite determiner (in this case "a") the preposition "for" can be used. It should also be taken into account that "of" is much more usual than "for", which will only be accepted in restricted contexts such as (2) above.

According to Seth Lindstromberg in *English Prepositions Explained*, while "of" expresses referential possession (the word **has** a definition) or a verb-object relationship (the word **is defined**), "for" expresses purpose (I want a definition **for the purpose of** defining this word).

Something similar can happen with other nouns, for example "solution":

- **The** solution **of** the problem is ...
- **A** solution **for** the problem could be ...

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14753/solution-for-or-solution-to-a-problem) is a good reply concerning the degree of idiomaticity of "a solution for" as compared with "a solution to" (in answer to Ram Pillai's comment below).

Comment: I think you're spot on, though it would be good to include a reference. // Perhaps the most commonly met examples are "What's the definition of xxxx?" and "The definition of xxxx is ..." (usually inaccurate, as decent dictionaries give various senses and subsenses for words). And here: (2) appropriate dictionary definitions of 'definition' would perhaps take up twenty to thirty lines for all the senses, four per 'definition', whereas an answer to (1) could run to pages. _And then there's 'definition' when judging the quality of photographs...._

Comment: A solution to the problem - is more appropriate. Can we say, 'A solution for the problem....'?

Comment: @RamPillai Thank you for your comment. I made an addition accordingly.

Comment: Does your answer also hold for "equation of" vs "equation for"?

Comment: @Bart Could you provide an example?

Comment: Similar remarks can be made with _the/an answer to/for this question_.

Comment: @Gustavson: Example sentence: "Plug the equation of/for the stress into the Navier-Stokes equation." That is, the Navier-Stokes equation contains a stress variable.

Comment: @John Lawler: I indeed hope to distill generic principles, rather than merely writing the case 'definition of/for' correct.

Comment: @Bart Alas, there are no generic principles for prepositions beyond their vague locational senses (_on the lawn, in the yard_). Like articles, there are hundreds of specialized cases that have to be learned individually with different constructions and predicates. Prepositions, articles, auxiliaries, pronouns -- all are just gears and washers in the syntax machine. Only certain ones will fit, and the decisions are arbitrary. It's like fixing a cranky old engine, which is a good description of English syntax.